# Custom contact form with google reCaptcha wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, recaptcha

Trying to implement a custom coded contact form with a google reCaptcha but nothing seems to be taking. This is using wordpress (don't wish to use the plugins' The validation comes back with "Thanks for posting comment." Get no email /message from the form, checked my junk mail etc. Any help would be appreciated. My HTML form is below:

```
<div class="contact_form">  
        <h1>Contact Form</h1>
        <form id="comment_form" action="" method="post">
          <p>Your Name (required) <br />
            <input type="text" name="cf-name" placeholder="type your name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" size="40" />
          </p>
          <p>Your Email (required) <br />
            <input type ="email" name="cf-email" placeholder="type your email" size ="40"><br>
          </p>
          <p>Subject (required)<br />
            <input type ="text" name="cf-subject" placeholder="type your subject" size ="40"><br>
          </p>
          <p>Your Message<br />
            <textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="cf-message"></textarea>
          </p>
          <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITEKEYHERE"></div>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment">
        </form>
      </div>
```

And my php to send email and check reCaptcha:

```
<?php

    // if the submit button is clicked, send the email
    if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {

        // sanitize form values
        $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-name"] );
        $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["cf-email"] );
        $subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-subject"] );
        $message = esc_textarea( $_POST["cf-message"] );

        // get the blog administrator's email address
        $to = "my@email.here";

        $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

        // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<p>Thanks for contacting me, expect a response soon.</p>';
            echo "$to";
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
          }
    }?>


    <?php

        $name;$email;$subject;$message;$captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['cf-name'])){
          $email=$_POST['cf-name'];
        }if(isset($_POST['cf-email'])){
          $email=$_POST['cf-email'];
        }if(isset($_POST['cf-subject'])){
          $email=$_POST['cf-subject'];
        }if(isset($_POST['cf-message'])){
          $email=$_POST['cf-message'];
        }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
          exit;
        }
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRETKEYHERE".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if($response.success==false)
        {
          echo '<h2>spam</h2>';
        }else
        {
          echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mailer code is being triggered before your validating your captcha.

Try moving your code around:

```
<?php

    $name;$email;$subject;$message;$captcha;
    if(isset($_POST['cf-name'])){
      $email=$_POST['cf-name'];
    }if(isset($_POST['cf-email'])){
      $email=$_POST['cf-email'];
    }if(isset($_POST['cf-subject'])){
      $email=$_POST['cf-subject'];
    }if(isset($_POST['cf-message'])){
      $email=$_POST['cf-message'];
    }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
      exit;
    }
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRETKEYHERE".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if($response.success==false){
      echo '<h2>spam</h2>';
    }else{
        // sanitize form values
        $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-name"] );
        $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["cf-email"] );
        $subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-subject"] );
        $message = esc_textarea( $_POST["cf-message"] );

        // get the blog administrator's email address
        $to = "my@email.here";

        $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

        // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<p>Thanks for contacting me, expect a response soon.</p>';
            echo "$to";
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
       }          

    }
?>
```

I'm tapping this out on my phone so you can tidy this code up a lot.
But the logic should be right.